# Check if page is in partial rendering mode ASP.NET 2.0 + AJAX.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, postback, ajax.net

I need to determine in the page is loading in a partial rendering mode (when posting back from within an UpdatePanel).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the 
[IsInAsyncPostBack](http:///asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/mref/P_System_Web_UI_ScriptManager_IsInAsyncPostBack.aspx) property of ScriptManager to check if the page is loading through a partial postback.